# How do I resize tmux pane by holding down prefix and arrow key for a while?

Tags: tmux

Ideally, I'd like it so that I can resize panes by some margin I'd want by just pressing down on the prefix + arrow keys and watch the panel resize till a point that I'm happy with, and I'd just lift my hand to stop the resizing.

Answer (score 67):

By default these bindings (among others) are active:

```
bind-key -r -T prefix       M-Up              resize-pane -U 5
bind-key -r -T prefix       M-Down            resize-pane -D 5
bind-key -r -T prefix       M-Left            resize-pane -L 5
bind-key -r -T prefix       M-Right           resize-pane -R 5
bind-key -r -T prefix       C-Up              resize-pane -U
bind-key -r -T prefix       C-Down            resize-pane -D
bind-key -r -T prefix       C-Left            resize-pane -L
bind-key -r -T prefix       C-Right           resize-pane -R
```

This means you can resize a pane by <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>Alt <kbd>←</kbd></kbd> or <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>Ctrl <kbd>↓</kbd></kbd> etc.

(The default <kbd>prefix</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>B</kbd></kbd>.)

Thanks to `-r` you can do <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>Ctrl <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>…</kbd> without repeating <kbd>prefix</kbd> many times, if you strike <kbd>↓</kbd> fast enough. Holding <kbd>↓</kbd> instead of striking it repeatedly may or may not work. If it doesn't work then it means `tmux` does not receive the second (or later) <kbd>↓</kbd> soon enough. In this case you can:

- Reconfigure your keyboard. E.g. in my Kubuntu the initial delay is 600 ms, which is higher than the default threshold of 500 ms used by `tmux`, therefore holding <kbd>↓</kbd> doesn't work by default. Then there will be 25 repeats per second, i.e. with the average interval of 40 ms, which is good enough for `tmux`. Changing 600 ms to 400 ms in the system-wide keyboard settings allows me to use <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>Ctrl <kbd>↓ <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd></kbd>.
- Reconfigure `tmux`. The behavior is governed by the [`repeat-time`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#repeat-time) option:

  > `repeat-time time`
  > Allow multiple commands to be entered without pressing the prefix-key again in the specified *time* milliseconds (the default is `500`). Whether a key repeats may be set when it is bound using the `-r` flag to `bind-key`. Repeat is enabled for the default keys bound to the `resize-pane` command.

  Example command (in a shell inside `tmux`):

  ```
    tmux set repeat-time 1000
  ```

  Or in `~/.tmux.conf` (permanent setting):

  ```
    set -g repeat-time 1000
  ```

Whichever method you choose (one or both), you want `repeat-time` in `tmux` to be higher than the delay and the repeat interval in your keyboard settings. Then you will even be able to

<kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>Ctrl <kbd>↓ <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd><kbd>↑ <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd><kbd>← <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd><kbd>→ <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd>…</kbd>

with just one <kbd>prefix</kbd> and without releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, if only you switch between <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> fast enough. If your <kbd>prefix</kbd> includes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then you don't need to release it. I mean with the default prefix of <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>B</kbd></kbd> you can do this:

<kbd>Ctrl <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>↓ <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd><kbd>↑ <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd><kbd>← <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd><kbd>→ <sub>(hold)</sub></kbd>…</kbd>

holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> during the *entire* sequence.

Comment: I'll point out, this mentions the use of default bindings. These bindings didn't use to exist so beware, you no longer need to set them.

Comment: I would like to do the same with vim `hjkl`, but I also have `bind-key -T root M-h select-pane -L` and it takes precedence over `bind-key -r -T prefix M-k resize-pane -U 5`, do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: @paime I don't expect `M-h` to get in conflict with `M-k` in any circumstances (`h` is not `k`, right?). But I don't experience any conflict between `-T root M-h` and `-T prefix M-h` either. Post a separate question; link to this answer if you think it provides context; include [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659), so I (or anyone) can replicate your problem.

Comment: Copy pasted the wrong line yes. Here it is as a question: https://superuser.com/q/1730620/1277454

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working anymore on Apple M1 Pro 2021. The `prefix       C-Up/Down/Left/Right`. I checked Keyboard shortcuts in Settings and didn't see anything overriding Ctrl up/down/left/right. I'm using iTerm 2 and tmux 3.2a.

Comment: @azizj I am having the same problem. Maybe ask in the dedicated vi stackexchange? Did you fix the issue?

Comment: I am also having a problem, but only with `prefix+Up(hold)`, all other directions resize the pane until I let go, but Up does not!

Answer (score 9):

To resize tmux panes, you’ll first want to hit your prefix — ctrl + b by default — and then the colon key :. What this does is brings up a prompt at the bottom of your screen.

Now you’ll want to type in resize-pane in the prompt, followed by a hyphen - and either D, U, L, R. Which you can probably guess stands for down, up, left and right, the direction in which you want your pane to be resized. When using the resize-pane command, the resize will be applied to the last pane that had focus.

Here is an example of the entire resize pane command that resizes the pane to the left by a cell — the unit in which tmux resizes:

```
// This assumes that you've hit ctrl + b and : to get to the command prompt :resize-pane -L
```

Here are some additional tmux pane resizing examples:

```
:resize-pane -D (Resizes the current pane down) 

:resize-pane -U (Resizes the current pane upward) 

:resize-pane -L (Resizes the current pane left) 

:resize-pane -R (Resizes the current pane right) 

:resize-pane -D 10 (Resizes the current pane down by 10 cells) 

:resize-pane -U 10 (Resizes the current pane upward by 10 cells) 

:resize-pane -L 10 (Resizes the current pane left by 10 cells) 

:resize-pane -R 10 (Resizes the current pane right by 10 cells)
```

Comment: OP asked about using the arrow keys. Using the prompt works for resizing, but not via the arrow keys.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.